# Why was my answer to this question about Adobe Illustrator files deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers

I'm extremely confused.

[I've provided an extensive explanation and answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/264720/238799) to the question "Can .ai files (Adobe Illustrator) be malicious?", yet it was deleted on some unclear grounds.

Why was this answer deleted?

Answer (score 6):

As you stated, you have no point, and you would not work with me to differentiate it from the existing answer. Then stated that you refused to work with me on improving it. You kinda left no choice.

Comment: AFAIK SE does **not** have rules against *"similar answers"* which is a very vague notion btw. This is not an "answer" btw. I welcome answers from other moderators because you're seemingly too vested and biased to deal with this situation. *"I don't like it, the user looks to be annoying, OK, I will promptly delete it"* - does not seem to be a valid behavior.

Comment: The criteria for answers on Meta are different than on the main site. And you can have whatever opinion you'd like and other mods and others of the community are perfectly free to answer. And of course I have a bias in this situation. No one would think otherwise I'm not sure why you are attacking this response and trying to attack me personally. Again. And, as I have said numerous times, my actions are not aimed at you but at what you have written. It is your choice to take it personally.

Comment: I have upvoted many of your answers. But where I see a problem, I try to work with you to improve them. You have consistently taken it personally, though.

Comment: My answer adds a **ton** of information not found in the existing one. I'm not a karma hoarder, I couldn't care less about it. I would like to see the exact SE (security) rules which allow you to delete the answer. I have zero desire to edit the existing answer since they are so different.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov - *you* think your post adds a lot of useful information, but it really doesn't. It gives nothing additional to a future visitor. Listing out the file formats that have been exploited doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: Then the existing "answer" doesn't address it either. Not only the person who gave the answer didn't provide the disassembly of Adobe Illustrator AI format parsing and rendering, he didn't analyze it to show where errors could be. I feel like moderators are here to defend each other's decisions no matter what, OK, so be it. I've just got a perfect confirmation of CJ. Thank you. Let me not mark this question solved because it's not. Vague pseudo-reasoning is vague.

Comment: If the other answer doesn't answer it, then repeating it isn't helpful, right? I think that you are entirely missing the point. Take a step back and instead of trying to defend your answer and lashing out at us, see it from our perspective.

Comment: I don't see justification for moderator delete on this answer. Downvote it, sure, but moderator delete should be reserved for spam, abuse, etc.

Comment: @paj28 or answers that simply repeat other answers or answers that do not answer the question. This is pretty standard across all SE sites. But then refusing to improve it when the mod is trying to guide a better answer, and there is another problem. I did not delete as a knee-jerk reaction.